# Low events date in the url

Tags: low-events

Is there any way of switching the date around in the url? I currently have /2015-07/ for a month and /2015-07/02/ for a day. But it would be great if i could get UK date range eg: /02-07-2015/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the URL variables in Low Events return a format according to the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), as this is always unambiguous.

Comment: Cheers for clearing that up